# Window is not restored after minimized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

WPF **window can't be restored** from the taskbar or using Alt+Tab after being minimized (it stays minimized). It happens on a part of environments (on my machine it's Ok but fails on some others).

I can switch to the window from Task manager - then it gets restored.

As a hotfix I added:

```
void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
   {
      this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
   }
}
```

It helped. But I don't think that is the best solution. Have you any other ideas to fix it?

Comment: "window can't be restored" you mean it stays minimized?

Comment: tray windows are not showing in alt+tab menu. You should add custom logic to you tray icon. for example window may be shown on double click

Comment: Your solution is right

Comment: Yes, window stays minimized.
Sorry, meant taskbar not tray.

Comment: you can call myWindow.Show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the best existing solution so far is the one I found:

```
void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
   {
      this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
   }
}
```